# Design of how to add two roles to one user with unique login

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, database-design

I want to ask you about your suggestion how can I deal with the problem. I have a table called `roles` where are: `client`, `worker`, `admin`. The second table is `user` where there are fields called: `id`, `login`, `password`, `roleID` -> `id` from `role` table, `login` which is unique. I also have a table called `worker` where I have regular fields and also `userID` which indicates which user he is. So it mean that he also have an information which `role` he has.

**The case:**
I want to add to the worker who already has a role `worker` a new role - `admin` on his user login. I can't add a new user with the same login, because each login has to be unique.

I mapped those classes to `SQL` table by using `hibernate-annotation`, which looks:

`Role`:

```
public class Role {

    private Integer roleId;
    private String name;
    private List<User> users;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole")
    @JsonBackReference
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
```

`User`:

```
public class User {

    private Integer userId;
    private String login;
    private Role userRole; // admin, worker, client
    private Worker userWorker;
    private Admin userAdmin;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Length(max = 40)
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER_ROLE_ID"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    public Role getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "workerUser")
    public Worker getUserWorker() {
        return userWorker;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userId")
    public Admin getUserAdmin() {
        return userAdmin;
    }
```

And the `Worker`:

```
public class Worker {

    private String workerPesel;
    private User workerUser;
    private Admin adminUser;

    @Id
    @Length(min = 11, max = 11)
    public String getWorkerPesel() {
        return workerPesel;
    }



    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    @JsonIgnore
    public User getWorkerUser() {
        return workerUser;
    }


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "worker")
    @JsonBackReference()
    public Admin getAdminUser() {
        return adminUser;
    }
```

As you see each `user` can has more than one `role`. But each `user` can be only one `worker`. `Admin` class is mapped to `Admin` table to hold users who are admins and they have `role = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you need ManyToMany relation. Introduce an additional table - `user_roles` and store pairs `user_id`, `role_id` in the table.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "USER_ROLES",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
)
@JsonBackReference
public List<User> getUsers() {
```

See the the example http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-annotations-example